# Error in plugin flutter_inappwebview-5.7.2+3 in Xcode 14.2 and Flutter version 3.3.10

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, dart, pub.dev

I try run app, but show the error in plugin
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.7.2+3/ios/Classes/Util.swift:135:24

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'UIScrollView.DecelerationRate' (aka 'CGFloat') has no member 'normal'
/Users/devdac/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.7.2+3/ios/Classes/Util.swift:143:18

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'UIScrollView.DecelerationRate' (aka 'CGFloat') has no member 'fast'
/Users/devdac/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.7.2+3/ios/Classes/Util.swift:145:18
```

I try run app in simulator Iphone 14 pro Max in Xcode
And message error show me
I run commands in folder ios
`pod deintegrate pod install  pod repo update pod update` 
`cd ..  flutter clean flutter pub cache repair flutter pub upgrade flutter pub get`

but nothing found!

Answer (score 0):

Add flutter_inappwebview plugin dependencies